# Power App- How to set blank value to metadata column using patch

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

Power App- How to set blank value to metadata column using patch

I am using patch function to save data in SharePoint list. While updating the list item if I clear the value of taxonomy field it should save blank value in list. How to do it. I tried with Blank() and null value.

Comment: There is a similar post for your reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Patch-blank/td-p/745070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above solution doesnt work for me. I explicitly pass below code to make it blank if value was already saved in list.

{
'@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedTaxonomy",
TermGuid: "",
WssId: -1,
Label: "",
Path: "",
Value: ""
}

Answer (score 0):

Try turning this on in Settings
[image]